# How to use NA in if..else if statement in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I created this small example. I want to print some values, for example, `B` for `NA` values using the `if else` statement.

```
x = c(1,7,NA, 3, NA, NA)

for(i in 1: length(x)){
  y = x[i]
  if(y == 1){
    print("A")
  }
  else if(y == 'NA'){
    print("B")
  }
  else{
    print("C")
  }
}
```

I am getting an error message `Error in if (y == 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` Why can't I print `B` for `NA` values? How to use `NA` within the `if else` statement?

Comment: You need `is.na(y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is also that `==` with `NA` returns NA and not FALSE.  Make sure to add a condition to check `NA` as well.  Also, `y == 'NA'` should be replaced with `is.na(y)`

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  y = x[i]
  if(y == 1 & !is.na(y)){
    print("A")
  }
  else if(is.na(y)){
    print("B")
  }
  else{
    print("C")
  }
}
```

-output

```
[1] "A"
[1] "C"
[1] "B"
[1] "C"
[1] "B"
[1] "B"
```

---

Or this can be done in a vectorized way

```
c("C", "B", "A")[1 + is.na(x) + 2 *(x %in% 1)]
#[1] "A" "C" "B" "C" "B" "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repetition, ensure that the first block checks for NA:

```
x = c(1,7,NA, 3, NA, NA)

for(i in 1: length(x)){
  y = x[i]
  if(is.na(y)){
    print("B")
  }
  else if(y == 1){
    print("A")
  }
  else{
    print("C")
  }
}

[1] "A"
[1] "C"
[1] "B"
[1] "C"
[1] "B"
[1] "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vectorized way using `case_when` or nested `ifelse` -

```
dplyr::case_when(is.na(x) ~ 'B', 
                 x == 1 ~ 'A', 
                 TRUE ~ 'C')

#[1] "A" "C" "B" "C" "B" "B"
```